# Why does my code behave differently compared to the old way I had written it?

Tags: java, arrays, object, for-loop

I'm working on a game and I'm trying to optimize things. I made a for loop to shorten the following code:

```
   // if near pb1

   if (pbMoveCheck_playerNearpb(pb1, pb2, b1, b2, b3, b4, m, p, x, y)
                & pbMoveCheck_doublepb(pb1, pb2, x, y)) {
            pb1Good = true;
            pGood = true;
        }

    // if near pb1
    if (pbMoveCheck_playerNearpb(pb1, pb3, b1, b2, b3, b4, m, p, x, y)
            & pbMoveCheck_doublepb(pb1, pb3, x, y)) {
        pb1Good = true;
        pGood = true;
    }

    // if near pb1
    if (pbMoveCheck_playerNearpb(pb1, pb4, b1, b2, b3, b4, m, p, x, y)
            & pbMoveCheck_doublepb(pb1, pb4, x, y)) {
        pb1Good = true;
        pGood = true;
    }

    // if near pb2
    if (pbMoveCheck_playerNearpb(pb2, pb1, b1, b2, b3, b4, m, p, x, y)
            & pbMoveCheck_doublepb(pb2, pb1, x, y)) {
        pb2Good = true;
        pGood = true;
    }

    // if near pb2
    if (pbMoveCheck_playerNearpb(pb2, pb3, b1, b2, b3, b4, m, p, x, y)
            & pbMoveCheck_doublepb(pb2, pb3, x, y)) {
        pb2Good = true;
        pGood = true;
    }

    // if near pb2
    if (pbMoveCheck_playerNearpb(pb2, pb4, b1, b2, b3, b4, m, p, x, y)
            & pbMoveCheck_doublepb(pb2, pb4, x, y)) {
        pb2Good = true;
        pGood = true;
    }

    // if near pb3
    if (pbMoveCheck_playerNearpb(pb3, pb1, b1, b2, b3, b4, m, p, x, y)
            & pbMoveCheck_doublepb(pb3, pb1, x, y)) {
        pb3Good = true;
        pGood = true;
    }

    // if near pb3
    if (pbMoveCheck_playerNearpb(pb3, pb2, b1, b2, b3, b4, m, p, x, y)
            & pbMoveCheck_doublepb(pb3, pb2, x, y)) {
        pb3Good = true;
        pGood = true;
    }

    // if near pb3
    if (pbMoveCheck_playerNearpb(pb3, pb4, b1, b2, b3, b4, m, p, x, y)
            & pbMoveCheck_doublepb(pb3, pb4, x, y)) {
        pb3Good = true;
        pGood = true;
    }

    // if near pb4
    if (pbMoveCheck_playerNearpb(pb4, pb1, b1, b2, b3, b4, m, p, x, y)
            & pbMoveCheck_doublepb(pb4, pb1, x, y)) {
        pb4Good = true;
        pGood = true;
    }

    // if near pb4
    if (pbMoveCheck_playerNearpb(pb4, pb2, b1, b2, b3, b4, m, p, x, y)
            & pbMoveCheck_doublepb(pb4, pb2, x, y)) {
        pb4Good = true;
        pGood = true;
    }

    // if near pb4
    if (pbMoveCheck_playerNearpb(pb4, pb3, b1, b2, b3, b4, m, p, x, y)
            & pbMoveCheck_doublepb(pb4, pb3, x, y)) {
        pb4Good = true;
        pGood = true;
    }
```

So I chopped it down to this:

```
    // Make lists of stuff
    pushBlock1[] listPushBlocksA = { pb1, pb2, pb3, pb4 };
    boolean[] pbGoodList = { pb1Good, pb2Good, pb3Good, pb4Good };


    // if near pb loop
    for (int i = 0; i < listPushBlocksA.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < listPushBlocksA.length; j++) {
            if (i != j & pbMoveCheck_playerNearpb(listPushBlocksA[i],
                    listPushBlocksA[j], b1, b2, b3, b4, m, p, x, y)
                    & pbMoveCheck_doublepb(listPushBlocksA[i],
                            listPushBlocksA[j], x, y)) {
                pbGoodList[i] = true;
                pGood = true;
            }
        }
    }
```

Something obviously didn't translate over when I redid the code because when I try to switch it in the game collisions that this is testing stop working. Can't for the life of me see what could be wrong, any ideas?

Comment: *Just as a sidenote:* passing 10 parameters to a method doesn't seem to be a good practice. I would suggest creating a [Value Object](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Value_object) class and pass an instance of that.

Comment: Thanks, I actually meant to go through and remove most of those parameters, I really just need the first two and x and y.

Comment: Then I would suggest that you do those modifications, check whether your modification works and then come back and ask a question (*in case you face any issues*). This will help you ask a concrete question, rather than a vague one like this.

Comment: Also use descriptive parameter/variable names where you can afford it. As it stands, this code leaves me cross eyed

Comment: Alright got rid of all the extra parameters but it didn't have anything to do with that unfortunately. Sorry for the confusing code that's why I'm trying to cut it down so much. For me I know what the variables are referring to because they're the first letters of my objects,but I can see why better names would be important once the code gets bigger, thanks.

Comment: Also, I guess for a concrete question, I just don't understand why my double for loop doesn't "extract" to produce the exact same longer code I originally had.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Use logical &&, not bit-wise & operator.
2. Consider

   ```
   boolean[] pbGoodList = { pb1Good, pb2Good, pb3Good, pb4Good }
   ```

   and

   ```
   pbGoodList[i] = true;
   ```

   You're NOT changing `pb1Good`, `pb2Good`, `pb3Good`, or `pb4Good` as you were doing in the original code shown.  While you initialized the array `pbGoodList` with those values, `pbGoodList` keeps uniquely different instances of those values.

   You could, after the loop, copy the values out of the array into the individual boolean variables:

   ```
   pb1Good = pbGoodList[0];
   ...
   ```

Comment: Awesome, thanks. Looking into && vs & which should optimize my code more in a bunch of places.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `&` operator, Change it to `&&`

Your `if` condition should be as follows:

```
if ((i != j) && (pbMoveCheck_playerNearpb(listPushBlocksA[i],
                listPushBlocksA[j], b1, b2, b3, b4, m, p, x, y)
                & pbMoveCheck_doublepb(listPushBlocksA[i],
                        listPushBlocksA[j], x, y)))
```

Comment: Still not the problem with the game behavior changing but I will keep in mind the difference between & and &&, very useful thanks.